# Alternatives to swfobject for embedding flashplayer

Tags: apache-flex, embed, flash, swfobject

Does anybody know if there's a better alternative to swfobject?
I actually like swfobject, I just wanted to hear if anybody found something better.
Or maybe it is the best way.

If you do not know swfobject you can find it here:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the best way I know of, and I have never had a problem with it.  Note that you cannot put JS in embed code for posting on some social networking sites such as Facebook.  In those cases you will need to use the usual object and embed tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can try ActiveContent, which is Adobe's solution for embedding flash. It's the default for flex builder, and (I believe) CS4.

You can find the source to this in the flex builder directory;

```
 $FLEX_BUILDER_LOCATION\sdks\3.3.0\templates\client-side-detection
```

Generally, people prefer swfobject because of it's simplicity. But activecontent is a field-tested solution.

Comment: I used to use this before I switched to swfobject.

Answer (score 1):

There are many alternatives to SWFObject, including SWF embedding code that ships with some popular JS frameworks, but none are as bulletproof as SWFObject.

Adobe is in the process of adopting SWFObject 2.x for most of its publishing products (SWFObject will replace Adobe's ActiveContent JavaScript-based solution).

BTW, If you use SWFObject's *static publishing* approach, your SWF **will** work *without* JavaScript being enabled. It simply won't have access to Adobe's ExpressInstall utility. See http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation#Should_I_use_the_static_or_dynamic_publishing_method?

You don't even need to download SWFObject if you use Google's Ajax API repository :)

Answer (score 0):

**[SWFObject 2](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).** The best way to get your flash movie seen by as many people as possible. (Except those with JavaScript turned off!)

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice "wrapper" for swfobject called "EasySWF". **They're using swfobject**, but just made it much easier to understand/implement.

From their documentation adding an SWF is as easy as:

```
easyswf({swf: "path/to/the.swf", width:400, height:100});
```

Here's the address:

http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/easyswf/

Looks like they're using it throughout their site as well?