# Flash active on page load

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript-3

I'm wondering,

I have a flash map included in my site usually like `<object...` and so on.

I have seen on some websites that on page load the flash is already active, I mean, on my map you have to first click on it and then start interacting with it.

I want to make it on page load already available for interaction, so user when hovers over flash it would already work, so that user doesn't need to click on the map to start interacting with it.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Embedding you Flash objects this way will ensure that the 'click to activate' IE stupidity doesn't happen, and also provides very easy solutions for the following:

- Flash Player Version checking
- Auto installation of latest FP version
- Fall-back content users without Flash and/or without JavaScript
- Ease of JavaScript -> Flash communication
- Events for detecting when Flash is actually added to the page

Comment: thanks for reply... Is there any other solutions? I was aware of SWFObject (though havn't used yet), I just want to know if there's any other then this one?

Comment: There's this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757883/alternatives-to-swfobject-for-embedding-flashplayer.  There was another viable alternative called UFO, but it merged with SWFObject a couple of years ago.  Adobe has their own solution that you can see if you allow Flash to generate an HTML file on publish, but I find it overly verbose.

Answer (score 0):

SWFObject is the definitive solution to adding Flash objects onto HTML. It's better than any solution Adobe have offered.